# How can I deserialization JSON in Windows Phone?

Tags: json, deserialization, windows-phone

The first JSON is look like [this](http://mobiilivantaa.lightscreenmedia.com/api/place/)

The second JSON is look like [this](http://mobiilivantaa.lightscreenmedia.com/api/place/243)

How can I deserialize them? I have been follow this [example](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.gr/2012/01/json-deserialization-with-jsonnet.html) but it's not working.
Here's my code.

```
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            var w = new WebClient();
            Observable
              .FromEvent<DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs>(w, "DownloadStringCompleted")
              .Subscribe(r =>
              {
                  var deserialized =
                    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Place>>(r.EventArgs.Result);
                  PlaceList.ItemsSource = deserialized;
              });
            w.DownloadStringAsync(
              new Uri("http://mobiilivantaa.lightscreenmedia.com/api/place"));

            //For 2nd JSON
            //w.DownloadStringAsync(
                 //new Uri("http://mobiilivantaa.lightscreenmedia.com/api/place/243"));

        }
```

These are classes for 1st JSON.

```
        public class Place
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string title { get; set; }
            public string latitude { get; set; }
            public string longitude { get; set; }
            public string www { get; set; }
        }

        public class RootObjectJSON1
        {
            public List<Place> Places { get; set; }
        }
```

These are classes for JSON2

```
public class Address
{
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string postal_code { get; set; }
    public string post_office { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string filename { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }
}

public class RootObjectJSON2
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string latitude { get; set; }
    public string longitude { get; set; }
    public string www { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string contact_person { get; set; }
    public Address address { get; set; }
    public List<Image> images { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks that you should be deserializing object RootObjectJSON1 or RootObjectJSON2, e.g.:

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObjectJSON1>(r.EventArgs.Result);
```

Also it seems that collection Places should be with lowercase p at beginning or you need to tell Json.NET that this property should be deserialized with different name, e.g.:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName="places")]
public List<Place> Places { get; set; }
```

Generally I tend to use arrays for deserialization (from my experience works better) so I'll suggest to rewrite it to this:

```
public class RootObjectJSON1
{
    public Place[] places { get; set; }
}
```

There is very good tool named json2csharp available at http://json2csharp.com/ - just put sample of JSON there and it will spit out classes in C# (doesn't detect DateTime so you might need to change that).